# Textures With Indirect Command Buffer

Tags: ios, graphics, 3d, game-engine, metal

I render with func drawIndexedPrimitives( type primitiveType: MTLPrimitiveType, indexType: MTLIndexType, indexBuffer: MTLBuffer, indexBufferOffset: Int, indirectBuffer: MTLBuffer, indirectBufferOffset: Int ), when I use Argument Buffer to set textures（e.g. to fragnent shader）, everything is fine. But is there a way to set textures without Argument Buffer? Argument Buffer is the only way?
When used with Argument Buffer, things go well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no other way. If you are using indirect command buffers, you have to get textures through argument buffers.

If you look at the API on the CPU:

- `MTLIndirectRenderCommand` only has `setVertexBuffer` and `setFragmentBuffer`.
- `MTLIndirectComputeCommand` only has `setKernelBuffer`

and on the GPU:

- `render_command` only has `set_vertex_bufer` and `set_fragment_buffer`
- `compute_command` only has `set_kernel_bufer`.